# Hungarian algorithm for multiple items auction with unit demand; How to get market clearing prices?

Tags: algorithms, economics, discrete-optimization, operations-research, algorithmic-game-theory

The well known "Hungarian Algorithm" is capable of finding a matching in a weighted bipartite graph with minimal (respectively maximal)  weight, and therefore can be used to find an optimal allocation of potential buyers to products, e.g. given valuations:
$$
\begin{matrix}
 & x & y & z\\
A & 4 & 0 & 0\\
B & 3 & 0 & 0\\
C & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{matrix}
$$
With A,B,C buyers, x,y,z products and buyer A has valuation 4 for product x, valuation 0 for product y and so on. Multiplying all elements by -1 and solving it, yields the assignement "A gets x, B gets y and C gets z":
$$
\begin{matrix}
 & x & y & z\\
A & 0* & 1 & 2\\
B & 0 & 0* & 1\\
C & 3 & 0 & 0*\\
\end{matrix}
$$
But how do I extract the market clearing prices when using the Hungarian algorithm?

(In my example, $x =\$ 3$, $y = z = 0$ dollars would be market clearing, as the utility of a buyer for product i is valuation(i) - price(i), and a buyer wants one of the items for which her utility is maximal).